# how to use if in two dataset at the same time - R

Tags: r, join, filter

One doubt, I need to compare two datasets by the same id number between them, and if it is the same, I need to divide a field in column x, by the field in column y.

ex.:

```
tableX <- as_tibble (tableX)
tableY <- as_tibble (tableY)

if (tableX $ id == tableY $ id) {
  tableX $ example <- tableY $ px / tableY $ px
}
```

Since they are two separate datasets, I don't know how to do this filter because of the number of rows in each dataset ([i]).
If anyone knows any function or anything that helps me, I am very grateful.

Comment: Can you `dput(tableX)` and `dput(tableY)` and paste the results into your question. It's easier to try some things if we have access to a sample of your data. If the data is too large, try `dput(head(tableX))`.

Comment: Also, are you certain you want ` tableY$px / tableY$px`? As long as the values aren't 0, NaN, Inf, or NA, this will always evaluate to 1.

Comment: It's hard to know what exactly you want to do without some data and example output. Perhaps you are looking to perform a join? E.g. you can create a new data.frame that contains only `id`s that occur in both `tableX` and `tableY` with `tableXY <- inner_join(tableX, tableY, on = 'id')`.

Comment: I get these dosi dataset from a postgres database, and I need to validate the information between them to generate a new dataset to write to a new database table. All the data in tableX and tableY follow the same pattern of number of columns and names, the difference between them are some numbers, which are the ones I need to compare them with.

Comment: It still sounds like a join would be the easiest way forward. Did you look up what I suggested? You are unlikely to receive a more useful answer without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A join is probably what you want. Then you can filter and compute whatever you need to.

```
library(dplyr)
# if you only want those rows with matching IDs in both tables
# Inner_join matches up the id values
tableX %>% 
  innner_join(tableY, by = "id") %>%
  mutate(example = ...)  # Where ... is the calculation you want to do

# If you want to keep all the rows in X even if there is not a match in Y
tableX %>%
  left_join(tableY, by = "id") %>% 
   mutate(example = ...)  # Where ... is the calculation you want to do

# If you want to do the left_join and have different behavior id there is a match or not
tableX %>%
  left_join(tableY, by = "id") %>% 
   mutate(example = case_when(is.na(table.Y.px) ~ ...,  # Where ... is the calculation you want to do
                              TRUE ~ ...) # How you want the rest of the cases to be treated
```

Comment: You'd probably want `ifelse` (or `if_else`) instead of `case_when`.